# Sql query in another query to find user location by longitude and latitude

Tags: mysql, sql, location, pivot

I am stuck on "basic" sql command. I have one table in WP ( usermeta ). In this table, I have **longitude** and **latitude** as **meta_key**. What I need is use two different queries to get list of **user_id**.

I have query that should be able to find users with dynamic distance every time I call it (that part "??SOMETHING??" is something unknown for me)

```
SELECT *, 
       (3959 * acos(cos(radians('LAT VAL')) * cos(radians(latitude)) 
         * cos( radians(longtitude) - radians('LNG VAL')) + sin(radians('LAT VAL')) 
         * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance 
FROM ??SOMETHING?? 
HAVING distance < 15 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Then I have this query ( really working )

```
SELECT user_id, 
       MAX(IF(meta_key = 'latitude', meta_value, NULL)) AS latitude,
       MAX(IF(meta_key = 'longitude', meta_value, NULL)) AS longitude 
FROM usermeta 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

I am doing it for hours now and I am not able figure it out alone. I think I am so close.

I will be very grateful, if someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the ??something?? with the query you have:

```
SELECT *, 
       (3959 * acos(cos(radians('LAT VAL')) * cos(radians(latitude)) 
         * cos( radians(longtitude) - radians('LNG VAL')) + sin(radians('LAT VAL')) 
         * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance 
FROM 
(
  SELECT user_id, 
       MAX(IF(meta_key = 'latitude', meta_value, NULL)) AS latitude,
       MAX(IF(meta_key = 'longitude', meta_value, NULL)) AS longitude 
  FROM usermeta 
  GROUP BY user_id
) a
HAVING distance < 15 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Please note, that in the query above the `'LAT VAL'` and `'LNG VAL'` are the coordinates of the point you want to find the users

Comment: I tried something like "IN ()". Thanks, I made some changes, it works now :)